# Get page based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know some web-based API that provides you page info ( title, etc ) from an url and argument?
Point here is that I don't want to load whole page, but just to receive json ( preferably )  with short info and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AlexaWebInfoService/2005-07-11/
(look at UrlInfo method)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe this is impossible to do from Javascript because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in browsers. If you want to get page data like that, you'll have to do it on the server.